# How can I achieve certain values of a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

In the following nested hash,

```
hash = {a: 2, b: 4, c: {name: "John", id: 12, age: 33}}
```

I want to return the values that are hash:

```
{:name => "John", :id => 12, :age => 33}
```

I want to returned a hash. I thought the following code will do the job:

```
hash.select! {|_k, v| v.is_a?(Hash)} 
# => {:c => {:name => "John", :id => 12, :age => 33}}
```

but I get both k/v pairs. Did I miss anything on the code? How can I achieve the return value as mentioned?

Comment: What would be the expected output for `{ a: { foo: 1 }, b: { foo: 2 } }`?

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
hash.values.find(&Hash.method(:===))
#=> {:name=>"John", :id=>12, :age=>33}
```

Comment: .values returns array but I am looking the return type be hash. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`select` returns the key and value that matched. Add `.values` to get just the values without the keys:

```
hash.select! { |_k, v| v.is_a?(Hash) }.values
```

This will return an array of the values that were matched by `select`:

```
[{:name=>"John", :id=>12, :age=>33}]
```

If you know there will only ever be one result, you can get the desired value by calling `first`:

```
hash.select! { |_k, v| v.is_a?(Hash) }.values.first
{:name=>"John", :id=>12, :age=>33}
```